# C# Convert string date and compare with other date times

Tags: c#, datetime, compare

I have three listboxes filled with items. Each item string begins with for example "Oct 26 12:07:33"... . When i click one item in one of the three listboxes in the other two listboxes an item with the same/closest time difference should be automatically selected.

I read the date time from an listbox Item and split the string.

```
string line = listBox2.SelectedItem as string;
string[] lineSplit = line.Split(" ");

string month = (lineSplit[0]);
string day = lineSplit[1];
string time = lineSplit[2];
```

Then i would create a list and fill it with the time differences. The line index with the closest difference is the index of my listbox item.

Looking in other listbox:

```
List<int> minDiff = new List<int>();

for (int k = 0; k < listBox3.Items.Count; k++)
{
    string listBox3Line = listBox3.Items[k].ToString();
    string[] listBox3lineSplit = listBox3Line.Split(" ");

    string listBox3month = listBox3lineSplit[0];
    string listBox3day = listBox3lineSplit[1];
    string listBox3time = listBox3lineSplit[2];

    -----Compare------ 



}
```

1. I cant convert this strings to date time  "String 'Oct/26/12:07:33' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
2. Is there another simple way to compare the strings and find the closest difference?
3. 

```
string month = "Oct";
string day = "26";
string time = "12:07:33";

DateTime enter_date = Convert.ToDateTime("Oct" + "/" + "26" + "/" + "12:07:33");
Console.WriteLine(enter_date);

----> "String 'Oct/26/12:07:33' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

---

(from comment)

The .txt files (log) with the date and timestamp will be generated on a device. I have no possibility and access to change this. I can just copy them to my local machine and read them.

Comment: Try to never have the DateTime as string as relevant info. Always have it as DateTime and only convert it to string(in the then cultural appropriate way for the current user) to show it somewhere. In a UI for example.  So your actual problem start with a counter question. Why is it a string in the first place?

Comment: The .txt files (log) with the date and timestamp will be generated on a device. I have no possibility and access to change this. I can just copy them to my local machine and read them. You mean with the compare question?

Comment: That would mean to me that when reading the file that you need to find out what format that string is. Like are the abbreviated Month names conforming to any standard in any culture. If yes then use DateTime.ParseExact with the known format as template to get a proper DateTime and use that in the follow up. Like displaying it somewhere in your listboxes, comparing them etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is "Oct/26/12:07:33" and assuming that is Month/Day/Hour:Minute/Second, then you can convert it to a DateTime by:

```cs
string text = "Oct/26/12:07:33";
DateTime date;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "MMM/dd/HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)) throw new System.FormatException($"Cannot parse {text} to date.");
// Do something with date.
```

But the date string is missing a year so be careful with comparisons.

**Edit**

Just noticed the start of your question has the string as "Oct 26 12:07:33", in which case

```cs
string text = "Oct 26 12:07:33";
DateTime date;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)) throw new System.FormatException($"Cannot parse {text} to date.");
// Do something with date.
```

Again, be careful with comparisons as you are still missing the year.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a solution

```
string month = "Jan";
string month = "Feb";
.
.
.
.
string month = "Oct";

if (month == "Oct")
{
    int monthInt = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(monthInt);
}

string day = "26";
int dayInt = Int32.Parse(day);
Console.WriteLine(dayInt);

//string time = "12:07:33";

string hour = "12";
int hourInt = Int32.Parse(hour);
Console.WriteLine(hourInt);

string minute = "07";
int minuteInt = Int32.Parse(minute);
Console.WriteLine(minuteInt);

string seconds = "33";
int secondsInt = Int32.Parse(seconds);
Console.WriteLine(secondsInt);
```

Convert each string pair like month, day, hour, minute, seconds and compare these values with the others. For this i have to do one more string split for the timestamp with ":".